# How to import from a module in the same directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I'm attempting to make a Python3.6 package, but have run into ModuleNotFound errors when importing from within the package. The package has the following structure:

```
project/
    project/
        cache/
            default.py
            interface.py
        __init__.py
        handler.py
test.py
```

The `__init__.py` file contains the following:

```
from .handler import Handler

def getHandler(access_token=None, **kwargs):
    return Handler(access_token, **kwargs)
```

And then within `handler.py`, I'm attempting to import from `cache` with the following:

```
from .cache.default import DefaultCache
```

The goal is to allow the following by client code:

```
import project

handler = project.getHandler()
```

That last import is failing, and I'm not clear why. Any ideas? TIA.

Not sure how relevant it is, but I'm testing this by running the following in the outer `project` directory:

```
> pip install .
> python3 ../test.py
```

This returns the following traceback

`(venv) Jamess-MacBook-Pro-2:project james$ python3 ../test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import project
  File "/Users/james/Work/Project/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/project/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .handler import Handler
  File "/Users/james/Work/Project/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/project/handler.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .cache.default import DefaultCache
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project.cache'`

Comment: remove starting `"."` from your import

Comment: Hmm I did that and now get the following error:

    from cache.default import DefaultCache
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cache'

Also I've updated the original question to include info about how I'm testing.

Comment: @mad_ Why? In Python 3, that would make it an absolute import, and there's nothing named `handler` directly under `sys.path`.

Comment: I can't reproduce this with your example, either locally or [on repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/KnownDeadlySection). Whether I run `python3 ../test.py` or `cd ..; python3 test.py`, the `import proejct`, `from .handler import Handler`, and `from .cache.default import DefaultCache` all work, and it exits without any errors.

Comment: You probably want an empty `cache/__init__.py`, but not having it shouldn't cause this problem (and doesn't for me); it makes `cache` an implicit namespace package instead of a regular package, but you can still import stuff out of it just fine.

Comment: Meanwhile, please show the exact error traceback instead of just describing it. I'm pretty sure I can guess what it is, but it would be better to not have to guess.

Comment: Finally: It's a little weird to design your package to `pip install .` and at the same time to run directly out of source. You probably want your test script to run out of the copy of your project installed to site-packages, but instead it's using the local copy. But, again, that probably isn't going to cause a problem here. (If that _is_ the problem, then you need to give us a [mcve] that includes a minimal `setup.py` along with everything else.)

Comment: @abarnert Word, I added the traceback to the original question. Re your last comment: this is interesting. I assumed that if I was installing the package into the virtualenv and then ran `test.py` script with the virtualenv activated, that it would use site-packages version. I take it that isn't the case?

Comment: Try `print(sys.path)`, and you'll see that the path to the main script comes _before_ your virtualenv's `site-packages` directory. Or at least that's the default behavior; see the [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path) docs and the links to `site` and `PYTHONPATH` from there.

Comment: From the traceback, the code you posted here isn't the same as your actual code. I can see the error from the traceback and guess at exactly what you did wrong, but please [edit] your question to a [mcve] that reproduces the error, instead of a different example that doesn't, so we (and future readers with a similar problem) don't have to guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your traceback:

```
  File "/Users/james/Work/Project/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/project/handler.py", line 7, in <module>
    from cache.default import DefaultCache
```

That's not the same as the code you showed us here:

```
from .cache.default import DefaultCache
```

The `.cache.default` is correct—that's a relative path from within `project`, so it will find `project.cache.default` in `project/cache/default.py`.

The `cache.default` without the leading dot in your actual code is an absolute path, from any of the directories in `sys.path`. Since there is no file or directory named `cache` in any of those directories, it fails.

---

Meanwhile, your project directory structure doesn't seem to be the same thing you showed us either. Otherwise, `import project` should not find the installed version. By default (and I don't think you've done anything to change it), the first entry in [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path) "is the directory containing the script that was used to invoke the Python interpreter". Which, given the structure you posted here, means that `import project` should find the `project` subdirectory in the same directory as `test.py`, not the one in your venv's `site-packages`.

Comment: Ah, you're right, I copied the wrong traceback. That was one where I was trying out a different import path. It's updated. Looks like the issue was that since `project` is nested (`/project/project`), and `test.py` is was in the same directory as the outer `project` directory, it was looking in a different place than I assumed. Thanks very much for the help!